# How to give the divs form the same width

Tags: html, css, forms

I tried to give the same width to these divs:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAJCK.png)

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <span class="control-label own">Ownership?</span>

             <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col radio radio-inline borders-check col-md-6">
                 <input type="radio" id="ownyes" name="ownership" value="ownershipYes" checked>
                 <label class="vert checkbox-checked" for="ownyes">Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col radio radio-inline borders-check col-md-6">
                 <input type="radio" id="ownno" name="ownership" value="ownershipNo">
                 <label class="vert checkbox-checked" for="ownno">No</label>    
              </div>
             </div>
     </div>
```

but I received this:

As you can see the second div goes down. What I must do?

Comment: Your second image doesn't seem to be linked

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAJCK.png

Comment: Some CSS might help us see clearer into your issue.

Comment: .form-horizontal .radio {
    min-height: 32px;
}
.form-horizontal .radio, .form-horizontal .checkbox, .form-horizontal .radio-inline, .form-horizontal .checkbox-inline {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.radio input[type="radio"], .radio-inline input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"], .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    line-height: normal;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}